# What does it mean Ethereum Swarm account?

Tags: swarm

ETH wallet is something like

> 0xd0a6e6c54dbc68db5db3a091b171a77407ff7ccf

I read Swarm docs and see

> in our example swarm --bzzaccount 2f1cd699b0bf461dcfbf0098ad8f5587b038f0f1
>
> (You should replace
> 2f1cd699b0bf461dcfbf0098ad8f5587b038f0f1 with your address).

I don't understand:

1. why swarm account format is different then ETH wallet format?
2. why i need swarm account after I'll upload data? I need this account to edit data?
3. does swarm has is own payment protocol?
4. how can I integrate/associate my own ETH wallet with my swarm account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. why swarm account format is different then ETH wallet format?

It's not. Address is 20 bytes (truncated hash of public key). You use the same "accounts" you create with `geth`.

> 2. why i need swarm account after I'll upload data? I need this account to edit data?

There really is not "editing" data in swarm, there's only replacing data. Data, once uploaded, can't be deleted or modified.

> 3. does swarm has is own payment protocol?

Yes, the account will be used for settlements of data transfer. This is not yet implemented. Furthermore, the public key encryption part of `pss` messaging also uses your "account" private key for decryption. And finally, if you want to use swarm feeds with the command line client, the private key from this "account" is used for signing the feed.

> 4. how can I integrate/associate my own ETH wallet with my swarm account?

The swarm node uses a keystore json file in the same format (and location) as the `geth` node does. Most wallets have the ability to export to this json format. However I'd recommend just creating a new account for the purpose of running swarm. You can create one by running `geth account new`. You will find the new keystore file in your datadir (`~/.ethereum/keystore` by default), and it can be used by specifying the address of it's "account" with the `--bzzaccount` flag as you've written yourself above.

If you don't have `geth`, then you would have to install that first.